# Unix Shell Script does not send intended email

Tags: shell, unix

I have a shell script like this. The purpose of this script is to tail+head out a certain amount of data from `file.csv` and then send it to email `Bob@123.com`. `DataFunction` seems to work fine alone however when I try to call `DataFunction` within the email function body. It seems it sends a empty email with the correct Title and destination. The body of the email is missing which should be the data from `DataFunction`. Is there a workaround for this ? Thank you in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash
DataFunction()
{
tail -10 /folder/"file.csv" | head -19
}
fnEmailFunction()
{
echo ${DataFunction}| mail -s Title Bob@123.com
}
fnEmailFunction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are echoing an unset variable, `$DataFunction` (written `${DataFunction}`), not invoking the function.

You should use:

```
DataFunction | mail -s Title Bob@123.com
```

You may have been trying to use:

```
echo $(DataFunction) | mail -s Title Bob@123.com
```

but that is misguided for several reasons.  The primary problem is that it converts the 10 lines of output from the `DataFunction` function into a single line of input to `mail`.  If you enclosed the `$(DataFunction)` in double quotes, that would preserve the 'shape' of the input, but it wastes time and energy compared to running the command (function) directly as shown.

Comment: Excellent solution Jonathan. Well thought out. Thank you very much for your effort. Next time I'll remember that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mail -s "Title" "bob@123com" <<EOF 
${DataFunction} 
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried @0xAX's answer and couldnt get it to work properly within a bash script.  You simply need to save the output of `DataFunction()` in some variable.  You can simply use these three lines to achieve this.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    VAR1=`tail -10 "/folder/file.csv" | head -19`
    echo $VAR1 | mail -s Title Bob@123.com
```